# Default sun doesn't do anything

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 1.3 allows you to grab and move the 'sun' that is included in the default world, but when I move it it seems to have no effect on the lighting, including the shadows that are projected and the light that is cast.  However, when I delete it the scene does go dark.  This seems to be a glitch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/426/default-sun-doesn%27t-do-anything/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Changing the position of a directional light doesn't affect the shadows; it's only the orientation that matters. Try using the rotate tool instead of the move tool, [as shown in this example video](https://vimeo.com/55116250).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1